# A good alternative to replace waitpid in a linux 2.6 kernel module?

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel

In my linux 2.6 kernel module, I created a kernel thread through kernel_thread function and specified the third argument as SIGCHLD. So when this child thread exits, it will send a SIGCHLD signal to the parent process. Correspondingly, in the parent process if there is pending signal SIGCHLD, I want it to wait for the termination of any child thread.

I know that in user-space linux provides waitpid system call. We can use it like 
waitpid(-1, 0, WNOHANG). What I am looking for is an alternative of waitpid which can be used in a kernel module.

Is there such an alternative or other possible mechanism?

Comment: I still haven't found a feasible solution. One possible solution I am trying is to explicitly export the sys_waitpid() or sys_wait4() from the kernel. But I highly doubt whether I can use them in a kernel module. Also, this hacking affects the portability of my module. Does anyone have any experience? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you cannot invoke kernel functions named "sys_" because these functions are intended to be called from user-space processes.  Any addresses passed *must* be user-space addresses and *not be* kernel address.  On the other hand, functions named "do_" are intended to be accessed using kernel context.

You should become familiar with Bovet/Cesati:

http://books.google.com/books?id=h0lltXyJ8aIC&pg=PT139&lpg=PT139&dq=kernel_thread+function&source=bl&ots=gO-sO038GQ&sig=yZSwg5h6BLO2BCzahNdEzX1TG7s&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XznsU4u2BOLLsQS404C4Dg&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=kernel_thread%20function&f=false

before attempting this.